# Google Cloud Console - 'Failed to evaluate expression' for Wordpress Deployment

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

Reference to Google Cloud, I have created a VM instance to host a Wordpress website where I used the Wordpress Deployment from the Marketplace in Google Cloud. I paid for them (not free tier). Everything was deployed successfully, and my website ran beautifully for my customer.

However, a few months later, my client complained that the website is no longer running, and when I accessed the Google Cloud Console, I realized that the VM instance is no longer listed in my VM instances. (Please see the screenshots below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbnoC.png)

I went to the Wordpress Deployment listing, and I found it there. However, the information showed that the URL's and the PHP MyAdmin links have red exclamation marks, with the note "Failed to evaluate expression".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2psu.png)

With this, is it possible to create a new instance and attach the wordpress deployment to it? or is there any way I can have Google restore my VM instance?

I tried to check if at all possible to create a new VM instance and then possibly try to attach the still existing Wordpress deployment to it, with no success..